Offset of a comparator

I'm confused about the offset of the comparator. Consider a comparator consisting of a pre-amp and an inverter. Does the offset come from the misalignment of the preamplifier's Vocm and the threshold of the inverter? Say, when Vref=Vin, Vocm of the pre-amp saturates the inverter, so Vin needs to be larger or smaller than Vref to make Vo=1/2*VDD. And a comparator with 0 offset means when Vref=Vin, Vo=1/2*VDD?
If my understanding is correct, the offset of the above comparator seems to be highly dependent on the process, and is not predictable.
In addition, let's consider this scenario: Vocm of the pre-amp matches the threshold voltage of the inverter, and when Vref=Vin, Vo=1/2*VDD. But the pre-amp doesn't have a linear transfer function. Does this also contribute to the offset? The voltage required to saturate inverter is different now, so the 'middle point' is shifted?

All of the above.
For a simple diagram like that, you're over-thinking it. For large pre-amp gain, the gain of the pre-amp will tend to dominate, so the pre-amp offsets will have more effect than the output stage offsets, where words like 'large' and 'tend' are left undefined.
If you want to design a real comparator, then you're under-thinking it. Draw a schematic at component level, and design and simulate it properly.

Thanks for your answer. I am simulating a comparator and am trying to investigate where the error is coming from. The pre-amp I'm using has quite a small gain, is it better to add more inverters to make the over all gain is sufficiently large? Seems that if the gain is small, the transition point will not be very precise.
